# Как подключить eot / svg / woff / ttf ссылкой?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, файлы, svg

У меня есть 4 файла, 4 разных типов, это eot/svg/woff/ttf.
Мне нужно перенести небольшой проект внутрь одного html файла.
Css и png я разумеется подключил и это было просто.
Однако тут подключено ещё 4 файла, есть ли возможность их подключить через ссылки?

В проекте подключение выглядит так:

```
src: url("cs-ctrl-rhomb.eot");
src: url("cs-ctrl-rhomb.woff") format("woff"),
     url("cs-ctrl-rhomb.ttf") format("truetype"),
     url("cs-ctrl-rhomb.svg#basic") format("svg");
```

Я сохранял данные 4 файла через vk и в итоге это выглядит так:

```
src: url("https://inlnk.ru/AKd4Bg.eot");
src: url("https://inlnk.ru/go9KNg.woff") format("woff"),
     url("https://inlnk.ru/kXewmo.ttf") format("truetype"),
     url("https://inlnk.ru/LAB1NL.svg#basic") format("svg");
```

Однако сами ссылки ведут к скачиванию файла и я даже не знаю валидно ли они работают после подключения. Сам проект после данной поправки работает также, единственное отличие это отсутствие изображений стрелок( я так понимаю svg не работает ).

Можно ли так подключить и если да, то через какой ресурс лучше сохранять/хранить файлы данного формата. Если так подключать нельзя, то как можно и возможно ли это вообще?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Можно ли так подключить и если да, то через какой ресурс лучше
> сохранять/хранить файлы данного формата. Если так подключать нельзя,
> то как можно и возможно ли это вообще?

Скорее всего нет. Посмотрите поддержку [SVG fonts](https://caniuse.com/?search=svg%20fonts)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видимо у вас очень старый проект, так уже давно не подключают шрифты.

Есть много, современных способов подключения шрифтов, где есть графические символы.

### Unicode

Ту же стрелку можно добавить с помощью юникодов, например есть спецраздел [стрелки](https://unicode-table.com/ru/sets/arrow-symbols/#right-arrows)

```css
.container {
width:400px;
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span style="color:red;font-size:42px">  &#129046;</span> ещё стрелки
   <span style="color:green;font-size:42px">  &#10147;</span> 
    <span style="color:purple;font-size:42px;font-weight:900">  </span>
      <span style="color:grey;font-size:42px;font-weight:900"> &#11122; </span>
        <span style="color:grey;font-size:42px;font-weight:900">    
&#11120; </span>
</div>
</div>
```

---

### Font Awesome

- Заходите на [сайт](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons?d=gallery&p=2&c=arrows), выбираете нужный символ стрелки
- Добавляете строку с указанием выбранного класса стрелки   `<i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-right"></i>`
- Подключаете стили Font Awesome

И всё готово,- любой графический символ, любая стрелка легко и просто появится в вашем приложении

---

```css
.fas  {
    color:purple;
    font-size:24px;
}
 .fad {
   color:green;
   font-size:24px;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-right"></i> 
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-to-right"></i>
    <i class="fad fa-arrow-alt-to-left"></i>
```

### Google-Fonts

**Google Material Icons**

Google воплотил  идеи символьного шрифта в реальность и создал свой [символьный шрифт](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#using-the-icons-in-html) -  ***svg иконок***, который включает в себя 900 изображений.

- Подключение шрифта:

  `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

Выбирать иконки по названиям можно [здесь](https://material.io/icons/)

- Наберите в строке поиска `arrow` и получите вывод всех стрелок

Пример использования гугловского символьного шрифта:

*Наведите курсор на иконки*

```css
span {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-top:2em;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
span:hover {
  transform: scale(4); 
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<span class="material-icons">east</span> 
<span class="material-icons">arrow_upward</span>
<span class="material-icons">arrow_downward</span>
<span class="material-icons">west</span>
```

Comment: Да я уже сам нашёл решение, но вы правы пришлось это перебрать, я просто таким даже и не пользовался, что раньше, что сейчас =)